# Joomla XML Feed doesn't show content

Tags: xml, joomla, rss, joomla-extensions

Im trying to get a this XML feed on my joomla website

[XML feed](https://www.managementboek.nl/code/affiliates/feed.php?affiliate=150&sort=7d&num=10)

I used a lot of different extensions but i don't get it to work, it keeps saying no content found.
The extentions that I tried are:
Module News Show Pro GK5,
News Show SP2, 
News xml rss feed scroll.

Some of them requires a RSS feed and not a XML feed so is there a way to convert this?
Is there an other way to do this or a extension that might work better? Or is there something wrong in my xml?

I hope you guys can help me out.

Comment: Pleas help us out, i got the same problem